# Efficiently accessing Pixels

Tags: haskell, image-processing, fractals

I just discovered [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159668/drawing-clifford-attractors-in-mathematica) and was wondering how to do something like that in Haskell. In the following I just simplify the part that I had difficulties with:

I have a list with a large number of 2D coordinates. For simplicitys sake let us assume that the list contains `Int` coordinates that are all in the range `0 - 1023`

```
points :: [(Int,Int)]  -- long list of points
```

The goal is now having an image (let us say `img :: [[Int]]` where `img` and each entry thereof has length `1024`) where `(img!!i)!!j` is the number of occurences of `(i,j)` in `points` (which would get mapped to some gray values).

**What I tried so far:**

1. If I just use the imperative approach of looping over `points` and trying to incerment the entry `i,j` of some 2d array, the part about picking some entry `i,j` and incrementing it is very cumbersome and probably not very efficient on the one hand, and on the other hand using `!!` is prone to `index too large` errors.
2. A slightly more efficinet approach: For each pairf of coordinates `(i,j)` use `partition` to filter out the `(i,j)` entries and count them, and pass the rest of the list to the next pair of coordnates. This way we get a list of `(i,j, count)` and we just have to plug `count` into each pixel `i,j` once, but this is still not very elegant in my opinion.

> So can you suggest any solutions on how to do this in more efficient and elegant *functional* way?

This is just meant as an exemplary problem, because I frequently ran into similar problems and only found unsatisfactory solutions.

---

EDIT: As requested here is an example of such code:

```hs
main = putStrLn "before:" >> print myImg  >> putStrLn "after:" >> print myImg2
       >> putStrLn "output of our \"image\":" >> print outImg

n :: Int
n = 4

-- example for "increment"
myImg = [[n..n+3]|n<-[1,5..16]] :: [[Int]]
myImg2 = increment myImg 2 3 10000

-- example for our application
zeroImg = [[0,0,0,0]|_<-[0,0,0,0]]
outImg = foldl (\img (i,j) -> increment img i j 1 ) zeroImg points

-- our "data" (here im just filling this with arbitrary numbers)
points = [(i `mod` n,j `mod` n)|i <-[1..14],j<-[i..77+i]] 


-- not very elegant code
increment :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
increment img i j v = a ++ [x ++ [y + v] ++ z] ++  c -- increments the "pixel" (i,j) by v
  where 
   a = take i img  
   b = img !! i
   c = drop (i+1) img
   x = take j b
   y = b !! j
   z = drop (j+1) b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLBbqMwEL37K145BUFQSbtbKdrmXqm3HgnaGjCJKdjImDRE@ffsGEraVYxk5pk3M28e3vPuQ9T15cIaLhWe0fb2zZpXBS8TpTZi7WGzQWuksmiGl2aHEV9ZvLTC3JBWDNP6j6t7SwC6hO4Ntp5s@E5svZ/ZRKF0xhTWa7woy5ymR8aWS4gjb9pagFTBkyo3ohHKemxS9YwkUVGkgof0rP4skzj8FUXx7zR1hZKESqXpRF0R95r@NdMKD4jvad10ckp529Yy51ZqxU7C6LnffTg@6fkvNZxByqYZiFHquqix2EpCCxlWPpabH63dsUSFGD7msq0mF7pRhevsFdxyD4u9MIL4qPrOopR1LdUOdi87fEq7BzeZtIabAapvMmE6n02FnMyFxHuji3eosJoj/yzhTCKLHtOwolBG0dNTIMkvNnZX2uIgqKKoxY6T2lwXgn2L/3bVDUXB7Wt2/XbiA@niCAIkx3EfEOCQuvA07shBEq55HY0q4LXyKGrvy8lswIEu2efojLttnGpa/kE2jW3Gs8z9agJ3d5AO54QLo1uqEcS@@@ROj3NmhczhgXDmciqHTtecyuVk7HL5Bw)

Comment: Some languages use those terms interchangeably and it depends on the language you are talking about, but that is not the point here. I don't think it matters a lot whether we use lists or not, the difficulty is about accessing and changing something using indices. If you insist you can replace this list with e.g. an `Image` from `Codec.Picture`, but my problem basically stays the same.

Comment: You question about *more efficient and elegant functional way*. So, I wrote what using lists it isn't efficient way. About *elegant functional way*, maybe if you add your solution it can help us to understand your problems here?

Comment: Usually it is not meaningful to solve such problems on Haskell, since you are starting from data that is convenient for imperative code. But you should to start from those data that are convenient for the functional way. For example, you can change this problem by adding two images. One of them will be your original image, the second one will be an image "created from your points".

Comment: How about this?
 https://wiki.haskell.org/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Vector_Tutorial#Generating_Vectors  "Vector is a Haskell library for working with arrays. It has an emphasis on very high performance ..."

Comment: @freestyle How would you generate the data from the linked example in a more functional way? I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but adding two images in each step does not seem very efficient, as only basically one pixel needs to be updated. I now added my solution with just a `4x4` instead of a `1024x1024` "image".

Answer (score 2):

You can use, as one of variants, `Data.Array`:

```
import Data.Array

main = do
    putStrLn "before:" >> print myArr
    putStrLn "after:" >> print myArr2
    putStrLn "output of our \"image\":" >> print outArr

n :: Int
n = 4

-- example for "increment"
myArr = listArray ((0,0), (n-1,n-1)) [1..]
myArr2 = accum (+) myArr [((2, 3), 1000)]

-- example for our application
outArr = accumArray (+) 0 ((0,0), (n-1,n-1)) [ (p, 1) | p <- points ]

-- our "data" (here im just filling this with arbitrary numbers)
points = [(i `mod` n,j `mod` n)|i <-[1..14],j<-[i..77+i]]
```

---

Using `repa` with `vector`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.Repa
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as MV

main = putStrLn "output of our \"image\":" >> print outArr

n :: Int
n = 1024

-- example for our application
outArr :: Array U DIM2 Int
outArr = fromUnboxed (Z :. n :. n) $ V.create $ do
    v <- MV.new (n * n)
    MV.set v 0
    forM_ points $ \(i, j) -> do
        let idx = i * n + j
        MV.modify v (+1) idx
    pure v

-- our "data" (here im just filling this with arbitrary numbers)
points = [(i `mod` n,j `mod` n)|i <-[1..14],j<-[i..77+i]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to do image processing in Haskell is with *Comonads*. It allows to specify image processing algorithms in an *elegant fuctional way*. A good and accessible introduction is https://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-11-27-comonads-image-processing.html.